# Check ajax response javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an ajax form on a page that receives a true or false response. What I am trying to do is check if the response exists or not and run javascript based on that, but I am a little stuck.

```
$( "#button" ).click(function() {

// if previous ajax response = true
// do nothing
// if previous ajax response is not = true or does not exist
   dosomething();

});
```

ajax:

```
                success:function(response){
                //log on success
                console.log(response);
                if(response == "true"){dosometing();}
                    if(response == "false"){alert("some alert");}
            },
            error:function(jqXHR,error){
                //write the error log
                console.log(jqXHR.status + " " + error);
            }
```

Maybe I'm not asking the right question.

EDIT 2: the ajax form is actually submitted elsewhere on the page. I'm just trying to see if it was called or not at some other point on the page.

Comment: Show us your ajax code.

Comment: There should be a failure function not sure what framework or library you are using for your Ajax call

Comment: AJAX is waiting for that `response`. To see if there is a response, unless your testing for falsey values, it's as simple as `if(response){}`, inside your `success` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out to check response has set.

```
if($.plainObject(response)){
    doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your web method return a value (exp: bool) you will find it in response.d

```
success:function(response){
                    //log on success
                    console.log(response.d);
                    if(response.d == "true"){dosometing();}
                        if(response.d == "false"){alert("some alert");}
                },
                error:function(jqXHR,error){
                    //write the error log
                    console.log(jqXHR.status + " " + error);
                }
```